# How to generate custom image dataset for object-detection?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, computer-vision, object-detection, image-preprocessing

I have to build a custom logo detector from e-commerce images.

I am aware of object detection techniques like YOLO, SSD etc and could find many resources on how to annotate a custom object detection dataset and train a object detector, for example https://medium.com/swlh/train-your-custom-object-detector-with-tensorflow-object-detector-api-65d38dcdf08c. However, in each of such articles, the images already had the concerned object and the process started from annotation step.

However in my case, I have a logo image and unlimited images without logo on which I would like to detect the logo to catch copyright infringement.

My questions are:

1. Which techniques can I use to place the logo automatically on the images to create a robust training dataset for my logo detector?
2. What pre-processing techniques should I use before annotating them using some tool?
3. Will it make any difference if I randomize the location of the logo on the training images versus if I put logos at the top left corner of each image for training data preparation?
4. For Single Shot Detectron (SSD), what other kinds of transformations are redundant in the training data? Like resizing the logo, changing its aspect ratio, etc. Are these useful variations or they won't make any difference?